# ServiceFabric Actor Reminder service is triggers 'ReceiveReminderAsync' muiltiple times instead of only once

Tags: azure-service-fabric, reminders, stateful-actor-service

Registering actor as follows:

```
ActorRuntime.RegisterActorAsync<JobTriggerActor>(
     context, actorType) => new ActorService(context, actorType)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

and by adding a breakpoint at the `ReceiveReminderAsync` method it's triggered 3 times after each duration.

Comment: Do you receive 3 reminders in 1 Actor, or 1 reminder each in 3 Actors?

Comment: @LoekD 3 reminders per 1 actor